# Connect to a VPN from a Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vpn, networkmanager, openvpn

I am running an Ubuntu distro inside a VMWare virtual machine with a bridged connection on a Windows 7 host. What I am trying to do is to have the virtual machine connect to a VPN, but I'm not having much success.

At first, the system was using wicd, but I replaced it with network-manager who's supposed to have OpenVPN support.

The problem is, even thogh I have purged the wicd installation, there are connections shown in the network manager, and still, I'm able to access the net. I've also added the openvpn data in the network manager tab, but it's shown as never used.

PS: When I try to stop and start the NetworkManager service, an error message pops up telling me that there's not such a service, but apt-get tells me I've already installed it...

Comment: What VPN are you trying to connect to? Can you reach (ping) the VPN gateway?